# onsubmit event doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, onsubmit

The following code will work in all my tests and works most of the time but it will not fire for all visitors.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#formane').on('submit', function(){
    jQuery.post('/storeit.php', jQuery(this).serialize(), function(){
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('error');
    });
  });
});
```

The storit.php page takes the data and tosses it into a database before the form posts to salesforce. I've tried removing jQuery completely, using onsubmit with a javascript function.

I get about 15% of form posts that just don't fire the code. They range in browser, OS and device.

Comment: There is not enough information here to diagnose this.

Comment: There is no guarantee the ajax request will even get a chance to fire before the form redirects the page

Comment: What else would you like to see?

Comment: Is this supposed to run in addition to the normal form submission, or instead of it?

Comment: In addition to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable the normal form submission, because when it reloads the page it will cancel the AJAX request. Instead, submit the form in the success function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#formane').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.post('/storeit.php', jQuery(this).serialize(), function(){
      console.log('success');
      $("#formane")[0].submit();
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('error');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.